# Didn't get Revelation due to insufficient free disk space, what to do now?

Tags: uplink

When I accepted the mission from ARC, I forgot to check my disk space - since I didn't have 4Gq of memory available, the copy of Revelation included with the email didn't download. Is there a way to get the file again now that I've cleared up my memory?

Thanks

Comment: Took me a minute to realise you meant *in-game* disk space! (I love seeing confusing questions about Uplink and Game Dev Story/Tycoon.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Heh, I can see how that can be confusing.

I've just copied my save and am trying to decrypt it and see if I can edit it to contain Revelation v1.

Comment: Also, I left that comment partly to head off anyone who is also confused and inspired to leave a (useless) answer about contacting customer support. ;)

Comment: No luck with a save editor. I'm just gonna keep going and ignore the ARC storyline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly a year later, I'm just going to answer my own question for posterity:

If you do not have 4 GigaQuads of free space upon receiving the email from ARC, you will not receive Revelation v1 and cannot continue the ARC storyline with this save file.